# Honda Civic hybrid won't start

Tags: honda, battery, civic, hybrid

My Honda Civic hybrid won't start.  No interior lights, no power.  Can I jump start the battery under the hood?  Not sure since it is a hybrid and has two? batteries.  I did not drive it for 3days.  It seems to be jerky/sluggish on acceleration for the past few weeks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can jump the 12v battery from another 12v source. Ensure you are using the jumper cables correctly (+ to + and - to -) and you shouldn't have any issues. Your suggestion of the vehicle being jerky/sluggish would have nothing to do with the 12v battery system. This would have to do with the gas engine itself, or with the high voltage battery system/electric motor.

Comment: Thank you! Instead of jumping, I charged it with a plug in battery charger. The battery holds charge overnight but within 48h, it lost 90% of the charge. Any idea what is draining it? Have not yet tried to start it; interior lights, etc work when charged.

Comment: @user12782 What year is your car? How old is the battery. Either the battery is too and and needs to be replaced or you have some electrical issues causing it to draw too much power when the engine is not running. I hope former is your problem as it's an easy fix.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the original problem I had with my 2007 Civic Hybrid, there was a parasitic drain through the immobilizer which is part of the interior fuse box by the drivers feet. Changed out the fuse box and fixed that problem.